# segment objects in a polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a polymorphic association, what I want to do now is get all of the them, but segment them by who they belong to.

My Question:

```
  has_many :question_participants
  has_many :users, through: :question_participants,
                   source: :questionable, source_type: 'User'
  has_many :groups, through: :question_participants,
                    source: :questionable, source_type: 'Group'


# question can be assigned to Company, Group, User
class QuestionParticipant < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :questionable, polymorphic: true
end
```

now what I want to do is f.ex loop through all questions that belong to users, or all questions that belongs to a group. How do I achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use scopes.
In your question.rb, add the following:

```
scope :user_questions, -> { includes(:question_participants).where(question_participants: { source_type: 'User' }) }
scope :group_questions, -> { includes(:question_participants).where(question_participants: { source_type: 'Group' }) }
```

Then you can access either through `Question.user_questions` and `Question.group_questions`.